# What is $\ln(e^{ix})$?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

What is $\ln(e^{ix})$? Why isn't it $ix$?

Comment: because complex logs have branches. Which branch are you working in?

Comment: The complex logarithm is multivalued and so the possible values are $\log(e^{ix})=i (x+2n\pi)$ for integer values of $n$

Comment: Thank you both.